# Separating compound and simple words

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I know this problem is probably best served with DP, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it with recursion as a brute force way.

Given a set of words, say {"sales", "person", "salesperson"}, determine which words are compound (that is, it is the combination of 2 or more words in the list). So in this case, salesperson = sales + person, and is compound.

I based my answer heavily off of this problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String[] test = { "salesperson", "sales", "person" };
    String[] output = simpleWords(test);


    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        System.out.println(output[i]);
}

static String[] simpleWords(String[] words) {
    if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        return null;

    ArrayList<String> simpleWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];
        Boolean isCompoundWord = breakWords(words, word);

        if (!isCompoundWord)
            simpleWords.add(word);
    }

    String[] retVal = new String[simpleWords.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < simpleWords.size(); i++)
        retVal[i] = simpleWords.get(i);

    return retVal;

}

static boolean breakWords(String[] words, String word) {
    int size = word.length();

    if (size == 0 ) return true;

    for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {

        if (compareWords(words, word.substring(0, j)) && breakWords(words, word.substring(j, word.length()))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

static boolean compareWords(String[] words, String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].equals(word))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem here is now that while it successfully identifies salesperson as a compound word, it will also identify sales and person as a compound word. Can this code be revised so that this recursive solution works? I'm having trouble coming up with how I can easily do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with recursivity

```
public static String[] simpleWords(String[] data) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : data) {
        if (!isCompound(data, word)) {
            list.add(word);
        }
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}

public static boolean isCompound(String[] data, String word) {
    return isCompound(data, word, 0);
}

public static boolean isCompound(String[] data, String word, int iteration) {
    if (data == null || word == null || word.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String str : data) {
        if (str.equals(word) && iteration > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (word.startsWith(str)) {
            String subword = word.substring(str.length());
            if (isCompound(data, subword, iteration + 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just call it like this:

```
String[] data = {"sales", "person", "salesperson"};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(simpleWords(data)));
```

Comment: Ah nice solution! I thought about tracking the iteration but I think I was too focused on my current solution I didn't want to break it up. Thanks!